# WinError 2 While installing smbus package via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

While Installing smbus The Same error kept occuring which was `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`
i am using python 3.7 and i am wondering why this error is occuring to install it i am using the command: `py -3.7 -m pip install smbus`

does anyone have a fix for the error message ?

Comment: Could you please provide the full pip output & traceback (e.g. on a paste site)?

Comment: BTW smbus looks like a linux specific package?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7tbvqvcM

Comment: What are you trying to eventually _do_ with that library?

Comment: @AKX as the OP commented below, he's trying to communicate with a LiquidCrystal i2c LCD.

Comment: @mara004 I read that much. I'm left wondering how they're connecting an i2c LCD to their Windows machine, for instance. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you simply cannot use smbus on Windows.

The [smbus pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/smbus/) points to [this linux kernel site](https://archive.kernel.org/oldwiki/i2c.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/I2C_Tools.html) [^1] as homepage, which then refers to a git repository with a subfolder [py-smbus/](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools.git/tree/py-smbus).

Your linked install log tells us pip calls the package's [setup.py](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools.git/tree/py-smbus/setup.py), which tries to build a binary extension, which does not work on windows since the referenced C extension [smbusmodule.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools.git/tree/py-smbus/smbusmodule.c) requires linux headers rsp. linux-only libraries (i2c).

Why did you want to install smbus on Windows in the first place? Are you sure you have the right package name? Or is it a dependency of some other library/tool you want to use? smbus itself seems to be something very low-level and barely documented, and has received very few commits for almost a decade.

[^1]: which BTW is marked as obsolete

Comment: There's a library I was trying to use called LiquidCrsyal i2c, which needed smbus to run, I thought at the time it was for windows as I couldn't find anywhere that  declared the os that it's for. Is there any alternative library that works with communication with an i2c Lcd?

Comment: Are you referring to https://github.com/pl31/python-liquidcrystal_i2c? If so, it actually requires [`pysmbus`](https://github.com/bjornt/pysmbus) (a different package, but also imported as `smbus`), which claims to be a pure python implementation of smbus communication.

Comment: Wait, though. Looking at pysmbus code, it posix-opens a `/dev/...` path. That also smells linux only. (Python's posix module is only available on unix-like systems.)